# Replace a string variable by line contains this string in other variable

Tags: php

I have variable that contains very long list, each line of this list is unique, example:

```
$list = "http://example.com/xcvdre4a/our_trip-2014.jpg
http://example.com/awe38fd/weeding.jpg
http://example.com/ds543gfd/church.jpg"
```

I have `foreach` script where I would like to replace word from `$variable` into full link from the list above:

```
$variable = "church.jpg";
// use the word from $variable to find a link from $list and replace $variable.
echo $variable;
// should be "http://example.com/notsorted/church.jpg"
```

How can I do it?

I thought to change `$list` into an array and compare each array value to `$variable`, but it's not very good solution when I have many variables to replace.

Comment: well how `http://example.com/notsorted/church.jpg` be when you are assigning `church.jpg` to variable .. btw you can do this by string concatenation

Comment: Is the $list variable a string separated by a space?

Comment: is separated by new line.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll have to `explode` your list on new lines (`PHP_EOL`) to get an array of URL, then check if the variable is a sub-string of any URL (with `strpos`) :

```
foreach (explode(PHP_EOL, $list) as $url) {
 if (strpos($url, $variable) !== false) {
  $variable = $url;
  break;
 }
}

echo $variable;
```

Output :

> http://example.com/ds543gfd/church.jpg

This code will return the first URL that match the variable. Remove the `break` if you want the last one instead, or use an array to store any corresponding URL you find.